# Approximate largest eigenvalue of Monodromy matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-equations, differential-calculus

Does anyone know the procedure (or have pseudo code) to approximating the largest eigenvalue of a monodromy matrix? Or even to approximate the monodromy matrix itself?

There is no explicit solution to acquire the fundamental matrix in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford the CPU time and storage, compute the monodromy matrix explicitly by solving $n$ IVPs with the vectors of the canonical basis.

Otherwise, use [Arnoldi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration), possibly in the default functions included in your computing environment (e.g., Matlab's `eigs`, or `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`), providing a callback function that evaluates `f(v)=Av` by solving an IVP.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Matlab so eigs will hopefully do it. I'm just a bit confused on how to calculate the matrix in the first place. I'm not completely familiar with this stuff, I've been following theexample linked below. http://imgur.com/DJyZOxN       From my understanding you need to factor out constants to obtain the fundemental matrix, is there a way of calculating it when MATLAB is telling me there's no explicit solution?

Comment: @Aidan2160 If you want to follow the Arnoldi approach, you don't need to compute the matrix, but you give Matlab a procedure that computes its action (see the examples with `Afun` on https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com). If you have doubts with definitions and basic facts about monodromy matrices, I am afraid that Mathoverflow is not the right place to ask about it.

Comment: I've been having a lot of trouble with this. I know this isn't the best thing to ask on here, but could I pay you to write up this code. Could pay 50 euro and send on the information by email. It seems like it should take 30 minutes to do